# How to generate 10 (3x3) matrices from (30x3) matrices and use it for rotation matrix

Tags: matlab, math, multiple-columns, rows, rotational-matrices

I have 10 data for b which I am reading from an excel file. I am trying to get 10 (3x3) rotation matrices by substituting in the matrix [1 0 0; 0 cos(a) -sin(a); 0 sin(a) cos(a)]. However, my code generates (30x3) matrices. Can I generate 10 3x3 matrices directly or is there a way to join the three consecutive rows together to make 10 3x3 matrices from (30x3) matrices?

```
syms a b
b = xlsread('C:\Desktop\Data.xlsx');
r = subs([1 0 0 0 cos(a) -sin(a) 0 sin(a) cos(a)], b)
rx = vec2mat(r,3)
```

Further developing the answer to get the final rotational matrix, the above structure is repeated thrice as shown below

```
syms a b c d rx ry rz rm
b = xlsread('C:\Desktop\Data.xlsx','A1:A10');
c = xlsread('C:\Desktop\Data.xlsx','B1:B10');
d = xlsread('C:\Desktop\Data.xlsx','C1:C10');

rx = reshape(vec2mat(subs([1 0 0 0 cosd(a) -sind(a) 0 sind(a) cosd(a)], b), 3).',3,3,numel(b));
ry = reshape(vec2mat(subs([cosd(a) 0 sind(a) 0 1 0 -sind(a) 0 cosd(a)], c), 3).',3,3,numel(b));
rz = reshape(vec2mat(subs([cosd(a) -sind(a) 0 sind(a) cosd(a) 0 0 0 1], d), 3).',3,3,numel(b));

rm = rx.*ry.*rz;
```

The answers given by the algorithm is right as follows for the angles (34, 0, 100) angles in degrees

```
[-cos((4*pi)/9), 0 , 0]
[0, -cos((4*pi)/9*cos((17*pi)/90), 0]
[0, 0, cos((17*pi)/90)]
```

instead of

```
rm =

    0.8623         0         0
         0   -0.7317         0
         0         0   -0.8486
```

I am looking for a single matrix solution with decimal values (Not in terms of pi).

Comment: How do you want these 10 matrices being stored? If a `3 x 3 x 10` array is ok, then just [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your final result: `rx = reshape(vec2mat(r, 3).', 3, 3, numel(b))`.

Comment: Thank you so much @HansHirse. It works well except that the values are given as cos(25)*cos(130) for example instead of  -0.3641. Is it possible to make it to decimal value

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59186509/edit) your question and add some more information regarding this? How do you even get something like `cos(25)*cos(130)`? Please show some outputs for a limited set of `b`.

Comment: @HansHirse I edited the question as you asked, Do you think the edit is alright since your answer is included in the edited question now?

Answer (score 2):

After your edit, I'm even more wondering, why you need [symbolic variables and functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html) in the first place, if your desired result should be plain numerical.

So, avoiding symbolics: For each of your (single) rotation matrices as well as the combined rotation matrix, set up an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). Then, you can use [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to generate the combined rotation matrix for each parameter set.

Here's some code:

```matlab
% Parameters (from file, ...)
b = [34, 20, 30];
c = [0, 21, 31];
d = [100, 22, 32];

% Anonymous functions: (Single) rotation matrices
rot_x = @(alpha) [1 0 0; 0 cos(alpha) -sin(alpha); 0 sin(alpha) cos(alpha)];
rot_y = @(beta) [cos(beta) 0 sin(beta); 0 1 0; -sin(beta) 0 cos(beta)];
rot_z = @(gamma) [cos(gamma) -sin(gamma) 0; sin(gamma) cos(gamma) 0; 0 0 1];

% Anonymous function: Combined rotation matrix
rot_m = @(alpha, beta, gamma) rot_x(alpha) .* rot_y(beta) .* rot_z(gamma);

% Calculate combined rotation matrix for all parameter sets
rot_mats = arrayfun(rot_m, b, c, d, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

We get the following output:

```
rot_mats =
{
  [1,1] =
     0.86232   0.00000   0.00000
    -0.00000  -0.73174  -0.00000
    -0.00000   0.00000  -0.84857

  [1,2] =
     0.54771   0.00000   0.00000
    -0.00000  -0.40807  -0.00000
    -0.00000   0.00000  -0.22352

  [1,3] =
     0.76310  -0.00000  -0.00000
     0.00000   0.12868   0.00000
     0.00000  -0.00000   0.14110
}
```

As you can see, the first one is exactly your example – but, please pay attention: In your edit, you used `sind` and `cosd`, whereas the data from your example indicate, you were using `sin` and `cos` here!

Hope that helps!

---

Disclaimer: Tested with Octave 5.1.0, but also works with MATLAB Online.